# Play2 - Query Web API

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to query the Wikipedia API, using the following code:

```
class WikiArticle(url : String) {

  var text : WSRequest = null

  def queryApi(): Unit = {
    text = WS.url(url)
    println(text);
  }
}
```

I am calling the code from here:

```
val wikiArticle = new WikiArticle("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=George%20Washington&redirects=true");
```

As far as I understand the documentation for PlayWS from here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS, the above code should return an object containing the text of the page I am accessing.

However, I am getting back the following object instead, which doesn't contain the text:

```
NingWSRequest(NingWSClient(com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig@40ac2d48),https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=George%20Washington&redirects=true,GET,EmptyBody,Map(),Map(),None,None,None,None,None,None,None)
```

I also tried to use a Future, following the Scala WS documentation:
package models

```
import com.ning.http.client.Response
import play.api.libs.ws.{WSRequest, WS}
import play.api.Play.current

import scala.concurrent.Future
class WikiArticle(url : String) {

  var text : WSRequest = null

  def queryApi(): Unit = {
    text = WS.url(url)
    val futureResponse : Future[Response] = text.get();
    println(futureResponse);
  }
}
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
Error:(17, 53) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[com.ning.http.client.Response]
    val futureResponse : Future[Response] = text.get();
```

How can I query the API using Play2?

Comment: You really should read more carefully the doc. `.url` prepare the request, but doesn't yet send it. It's done when calling `.get` (GET request). Then you have to understand how `Future` works. Nothing specific to Play API about that.

Comment: Thank you! Do you recommend any resources for reading about them?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future & https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS